# Ressources en français avec transcriptions, excepté films et livres audio

Tags: ressources, oral

Pour améliorer ma compétence d'écoute, je voudrais écouter (ou regarder) du français et puis lire la transcription. Je ne suis pas à la recherche de films, car il faut leur consacrer trop de temps  (et il serait insolite de lire leurs transcriptions sans les regarder de concert), ni de livres audio, car leurs dictée est affectée et n'équivaut pas à la rapide élocution de tous les jours. J'ai déjà trouvé des pistes [ici](http://www.lingq.com/fr/forum/6/15893/) et [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6436/1995).

Qui d'autre fournit la transcription pour l'audio et la vidéo ? Jusqu'à présent, je n'ai pu trouver que [Le Journal en français facile](http://www.rfi.fr/lffr/statiques/accueil_apprendre.asp) sur RFI. Pourtant, je voudrais écouter en français au niveau difficile.

Par exemple, j'ai trouvé [Le Journal de TV5Monde](http://www.tv5mondeplus.com/emission/journal-tv5monde?nid=436673Il). Le mot « transcription » apparaît dans la page, mais rien ne se passe quand j'y clique. Merci de proposer ou suggérer d'autres chaînes ou sites Internet ?

Comment: Le plus agréable pour moi c'est de regarder des films et documentaire en français avec sous titre français.<br>
(la plupart des films ont leur sous titre légalement disponible sur internet). Je fais ça de mon coté pour garder mon niveau d'anglais et ça permet de connaître l'humour/la culture de la langue.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a un tas de vidéos en français avec des sous-titres également en français sur Amara:

http://www.amara.org/en/search/#/?q=&video_lang=fr&langs=fr

Answer (score 0):

Il y a quelque chose qui ressemble à ce que vous cherchez avec le site de l'[Assemblée Nationale](http://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/).

Par exemple, **2ème séance : Egalité entre les femmes et les hommes (suite) (de l'article 16 à la fin)**, dont on peut trouver la vidéo de séance [ici](http://videos.assemblee-nationale.fr/video.5122.2eme-seance--egalite-entre-les-femmes-et-les-hommes-suite-de-l-article-16-a-la-fin-24-janvier-2014), et la retranscription de cette même séance [là](http://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/14/cri/2013-2014/20140144.asp).

La retranscription n'est malheureusement pas très rigoureuse par rapport l'oral.

Le français qu'on y trouve est.. *à vau-l'eau*.

Il y a sans doute le même genre de chose sur le site du Sénat.

Answer (score 0):

Après avoir hasarder https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&q=francais+transcription+web&spell=1&sa=X&ei=Y6j5UoP9AamjiAf8sYG4BQ&ved=0CCYQvwUoAA&biw=1366&bih=638, j'arrive à www.lingq.com, d'où provient

https://www.google.com/search?q=francais+transcription+web+site:www.lingq.com&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&biw=1366&bih=638

et qui comporte

♦ Il faut s'inscrire pour TV 5.

Il y a plusieurs émissions de télé avec les sous-titres

Sinon, voici la page "Comprendre les documents vidéos"

http://www.tv5.org/TV5Site/enseigner-apprendre-...

♦ Vous trouverez des transcriptions aussi sur cette page. - See more at: http://www.lingq.com/fr/forum/16/9396/#sthash.vZKOSfWL.dpuf

♦ French videos: http://french.yabla.com/ (sous-titres en français). - See more at: http://www.lingq.com/fr/forum/16/9396/#sthash.vZKOSfWL.dpuf

♦ http://www.youtube.com/user/7jours
- See more at: http://www.lingq.com/fr/forum/16/9396/#sthash.vZKOSfWL.dpuf