# Que signifie « à vau-l'eau » dans ces contextes ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

> [...] c’est infernal ce qu’on nous demande et donc ça part à
> vau-l’eau. (un [directeur d'école](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/2022-01-13/france/les-profs-en-greve-contre-la-valse-des-protocoles-covid-19.php) au sujet des protocoles
> sanitaires)
>
> Le français qu'on y trouve est.. *à vau-l'eau*. (Istao, [ici-même](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8584))

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vau-leau/81217#176740) en ligne dit « péricliter peu à peu » avec aller/s'en aller, [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_vau-l%E2%80%99eau) dit « sans maîtrise, sans qu'on puisse le retenir ». Je ne comprends pas plus ce que le directeur dit des protocoles ou de la situation, dit-il « ça ne marche pas » ou autrement et Istao dit-il que le français est sous la norme ?

Peut-on expliquer ce que *(partir) à vau-l'eau* signifie dans les deux cas et s'agit-il de deux sens distincts et peut-on étayer davantage le sens de la locution *à vau-l'eau* et dire généralement si son emploi est courant ?

Comment: Ça va sans qu'on puisse le contrôler, ils n'arrivent plus à maîtriser ce qui se passe dans les écoles. C'est plus surprenant de dire que  « Le français qu'on y trouve est à vau-l'eau », car en général l'expression s'emploie avec un verbe de mouvement. Je comprends que dans la mesure où « La retranscription n'[étant] malheureusement pas très rigoureuse », la qualité  du français des sous-titres n'est pas bonne, il y a une différence de qualité entre l'oral et l'écrit.  Je comprends que celui qui a écrit la phrase fait référence au manque de rigueur de la part de ceux qui font les sous-titres.

Comment: Meilleure référence sur  [cette page](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aller_%C3%A0_vau-l%E2%80%99eau) du wiktionnaire. On y emploie *être à vau l’eau* pour vouloir dire qui fonctionne mal (rare à mon avis comme emploi) « Le français qu'on y trouve est.. à vau-l'eau » : il veut dire le français fonctionne mal, emploi un peu bizarre (ce n'est pas vraiment le français qui ne fonctionne pas à mon avis) et les points de suspension montre que le locuteur a hésité sur la formulation.

Comment: @None Donc j'avais compris le propos de Istao au contexte et en dépit de l'emploi qu'il a fait de l'expression sans verbe de mouvement. Je pensais comprendre davantage quelque chose de très nuancé, qui allait vraiment plus loin que ma compréhension sommaire mais pas vraiment finalement, c'est probablement simplement les associations dûes aux composés et avec des tournures qui me sont familières qui m'ont entraîné un peu hors-piste ou je ne sais quoi. Ça arrive que le hamster dans le cerveau courre plus vite que la roue de la langue disons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est une expression plutôt soutenue mais comprise. Aller à vau-l'eau, partir à vau-l'eau signifie perdre tout sens, partir à la dérive, devenir n'importe quoi.

Dans la première phrase, les protocoles sanitaires changent tellement souvent de direction qu'ils en deviennent inapplicables, perdent leur crédibilité.

Dans la deuxième phrase, le sens est similaire, le français qu'on y trouve est à la dérive.

Comment: Je comprends mieux _ça devient du n'importe quoi_. Spontanément je comprenais un truc comme ça s'étiole et devient de moins en moins appliqué, mais ce n'est pas ce qui est dit. Étrangement je pensais que partir à la dérive signifiait ce que l'expression signifie ici mais il semble qu'il n'y a pas vraiment d'emploi au figuré pour ça. Je pense que ça correspond un peu à _ça prend le bord_, que je comprends différemment de ce que Wiktionnaire dit de ça. Maudit que c'est compliqué, la langue. C'est vraiment la première fois de ma vie que je rencontre l'expression.

Comment: @NoëlloMiqueron La première fois que je l'ai entendu, je croyais que ça s'écrivait *à volo* ;-)

Comment: _Awolo_ hahahah. Les jésuites seraient fiers !

Answer (score 1):

La réponse de @jiliagre est bonne

Je voudrait préciser que `partir à la dérive` n'implique pas la passivité, bien au contraire.
Dans une administration, c'est souvent l'accumulation non-concertée des mesures réactives qui font que les choses partent à vau-l'eau. On peut faire l'analogie avec des rameurs sur un radeau qui pagaient chacun dans leur sens.
C'est clairement ce sens qu'il faut prendre quant au protocole sanitaire.